# recursion global variable return

Tags: python, recursion

In a certain condition I want to count up and return that value 
 
but when I use recursion it reset the value
so I tried to use global variable 
but it said

> NameError: name 'count' is not defined

Here is my recursion code

```
def solution(relation):
    global count
    df = pd.DataFrame(relation)
    for i in range(len(relation[0])):
        for j in range(len(relation[0])):
            if j != i: 
                temp = df[i] + df[j]
            else:
                temp = df[j]
            if(len(temp)==len(set(temp))):
                count +=1
                for jj in range(len(relation)):
                    relation[jj] = relation[jj][1:]
                return solution(relation)

    return count
```

Comment: you need to declare `count` also outside the `def`

Answer (score 2):

You must declare `count` also outside of function. Like this :

```
count = 0
def my_function(relation)
    global count
    # code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using as global variable pass it to the recursion and then update it
By calling with updated count

for E.g

```
def solution(relation, count=0):
     """ Your code logic"""
     solution(relation, count=count)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use it as a global variable, define it outside the function and it will work.

```
count = 0
def solution(relation):
    df = pd.DataFrame(relation)
    for i in range(len(relation[0])):
        for j in range(len(relation[0])):
            if j != i: 
                temp = df[i] + df[j]
            else:
                temp = df[j]
            if(len(temp)==len(set(temp))):
                count +=1
                for jj in range(len(relation)):
                    relation[jj] = relation[jj][1:]
                return solution(relation)

    return count
```

But this is a bad practice since it will expose an internal variable to outside unnecessarily. So the best way is passing it as an argument as mentioned in the other solution.